# How to show only skills when searchbar on tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have already implement tableview and searchbar, and show **skills vName** on row and **trade VName** on section
my issue is,
I want to show only **skills vName** when search in searchbar in updateSearchResultsForSearchController method

i have tried that method but cannot success.

#JSON Response from API

```
       {
           "category": [
               {
                   "iTraderCategoryId": "001",
                   "vName": "Build",
                   "vCategoryCode": "builder",
                    "skill": [
                       {
                           "iTraderSkillId": "1",
                           "iTraderCategoryId": "11",
                           "vName": "skillName1"
                       },
                       {
                           "iTraderSkillId": "2",
                           "iTraderCategoryId": "22",
                           "vName": "skillName2"
                       }
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "iTraderCategoryId": "002",
                   "vName": "TV",
                   "vCategoryCode": "tv",
                   "skill": [
                       {
                           "iTraderSkillId": "3",
                           "iTraderCategoryId": "33",
                           "vName": "skillName3"
                       },
                       {
                           "iTraderSkillId": "4",
                           "iTraderCategoryId": "44",
                           "vName": "skillName4"
                       },
                       {
                           "iTraderSkillId": "5",
                           "iTraderCategoryId": "55",
                           "vName": "skillName5"
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
```

#my tableview controller code is,

```
 import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Alamofire
import RxSwift

//class SectionTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {
class SectionTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate  {
    
    
    
    var selectedIngredients : Set<IndexPath> = []
    var searchController : UISearchController!
    var searchTradeSkills : UISearchController!
    
    var selectedTrad: Trade?
    
    var filteredObjects = [SkillDTO]()
    var isSearching = false
    var lastSelectedIndexPath : Int?
    var totalSkills = [Int : Bool]()
    
    //    var filterData : [String]!
    
    private let viewModel = TradeSelectionViewModel()
    var selectedTradeHandler: ((_ trade: Trade) -> Void)?
    private let bag = DisposeBag()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        searchBarSetup()
        callAPI()
        
    }
    func searchBarSetup() {
        
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        
        
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
    
    func callAPI(){
        
        UserApi().getTradieSkills().subscribe(onNext: { (result: Result<TradeSelectionViewModel>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(model: _):
                print(result)
            case .error(error: _):
                print("error")
                
            }
        }).disposed(by: bag)
    }
    
    
    
    // i don't know how to implement and show only skills when search
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        
        let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text!
        
        print(viewModel.categorySkills)
        if searchString.isEmpty {
            filteredObjects.removeAll()
        }else{
            
            let filterObject = viewModel.categorySkills.map({
                $0.skill
            })
            .reduce([], +).filter({
                ($0.vName?.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased()))!
            })
            
            filteredObjects = filterObject
            
            //    print("filter data is \(filteredObjects)")
            //                    let filterObject = viewModel.categorySkills.map({
            //                        $0.skill
            //                    })
            //                    .reduce([], +).filter({
            //                        ($0.vName?.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased()))!
            //                    })
            
            //                    let filterObjects = viewModel.catSkills.compactMap({
            //                        $0.vName?.filter({
            //                            $0.lowercased().contains(searchString.lowercased())
            //                        })
            //                    })
            
            //    filteredObjects = filterObject
            
   //         print("filter data count is in search before \(filteredObjects.count)")
            //    print("filter data is \(filteredObjects)")
            
        }
        
        if searchController.isActive {
            
            isSearching = true
        }else{
            isSearching = false
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
            return viewModel.categorySkills.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if isSearching && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
           
            return filteredObjects.count
            //return filteredObjects[section].skillName.count
            
            //    return filteredObjects[section].count  //final
        }else{
            let section = viewModel.categorySkills[section]
            return section.skill.count
        }
        
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if isSearching && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            let text =
                filteredObjects[indexPath.row].vName
            cell.textLabel?.text = text
        }else{
            cell.textLabel?.text = viewModel.categorySkills[indexPath.section].skill[indexPath.row].vName
            
        }
        if selectedIngredients.contains(indexPath){
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }else{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            cell.backgroundColor = .none
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        
        
        let titleText = viewModel.categorySkills[section].vName
        return titleText
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath.section
        if self.selectedIngredients.contains(indexPath){
            self.selectedIngredients.remove(indexPath)
            totalSkills[indexPath.row] = false
        }else{
            self.selectedIngredients.insert(indexPath)
            totalSkills[indexPath.row] = true
            
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        print(selectedIngredients)
        if lastSelectedIndexPath != nil {
            if lastSelectedIndexPath != indexPath.section {
                selectedIngredients.removeAll()
                print(selectedIngredients)
            }
        }
        
        return indexPath
    }
    
    
}
```

## Trade Structure

```
 import Foundation
    
    struct Trade {
        let categoryId: String
        let trade: String
        let skill : [Skills]
    }
    
    struct Skills {
        let skillId: String
        let skillName: String
    }
```

#ViewModelFile

```
    import Foundation
                import RealmSwift
                
                class TradeSelectionViewModel {
                    
                    init() {
                        load()
                    }
                    private(set) var trades: [Trade] = []
                    
                    var categorySkills : Results<TradeCategorySkillDTO> = DataManager.shared.get()
                    private func load() {
                        trades.removeAll()
                        
                        categorySkills = categorySkills.sorted(byKeyPath: "vName")
                        categorySkills.forEach({
                            trades.append(Trade(categoryId: $0.iTraderCategoryID, trade: $0.vName))
                        })
                   //     print(trades)
                    } 
                }
```

RealmFile for Trade data

```
        import Foundation
        import Realm
        import RealmSwift
        
        @objcMembers class TradeCategorySkillDTO: Object, Codable {
            dynamic var iTraderCategoryID: String = ""
            dynamic var vName: String = ""
            dynamic var skill = List<SkillDTO>()
        
            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case iTraderCategoryID = "iTraderCategoryId"
                case vName
                case skill
            }
            
            override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
                return "iTraderCategoryID"
            }
        }
```

RealmFile for Skill Data

```
        import Foundation
        import Realm
        import RealmSwift
        
        @objcMembers class SkillDTO: Object, Codable {
            dynamic var iTraderSkillID: String = ""
            dynamic var iTraderCategoryID: String = ""
            dynamic var vName: String?
        
            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case iTraderSkillID = "iTraderSkillId"
                case iTraderCategoryID = "iTraderCategoryId"
                case vName
            }
            
            override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
                return "iTraderSkillID"
            }
        }
```

Comment: There are a few issues with the code but the question is really unclear. You ask how to access `iTraderSkillID in file2 inside trades` and there's *nothing* in File 2 that references `iTraderSkillID`. File 2 reads some Realm objects and creates an array of `Trade` objects with this `Trade(categoryId: $0.iTraderCategoryID, trade: $0.vName` which has no reference to `iTraderSkillID` - therefore none of the objects contain that.

Comment: @Jay yes, no reference, that what I want to know, how to reference ' iTraderSkillID ' in file 2 and use with trades.

Comment: That's still unclear; what's preventing you from instantiating a `SkillDTO` object within file 2 and accessing its properties? e.g. within file 2 add a property `dynamic mySkill = SkillDTO()` and then populate the properties `mySkill. iTraderSkillID = "Hello"`? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay I have edited my question with response and details.

Comment: Here's your question *How to access below variables from file 4 to file 2 variable*. Please look at your FILE 4 - there is nothing in FILE 4 that references the object in FILE 2 `TradeSelectionViewModel`. And there is NOTHING in FILE 2 that references the object in FILE 4 `SkillDTO`. So you can't access the vars in either object because the objects don't know about each other. If you want to have FILE 4 access variables in the FILE 2 object `TradeSelectionViewModel` add it to FILE 4 `let myTradeSelectionViewModel = TradeSelectionViewModel()`

Comment: In the edit section - I see what your doing there; it's a tableView with section headers coming from your Firebase structure field vName; which is Build, TV etc and then the child rows in each section which comes from the skills. However, there appears to be question in that section but I want to sort Skill's Vname when search on searchbar which is unrelated to the initial question, so now there's two questions? Or...? We want to help by what's being asked is unclear.

Comment: @Jay sorry for wrong way to ask a question,
please refer again and help.
if any clarification required let me know.

Comment: *I want to sort only skills vName when search in searchbar* what does sorting have to do with the searchbar, which is used for searching? The data in your tableView dataSource would already be sorted so it's displays correctly in the tableview - so...? I am not sure why the question includes the tableView code since you are asking about the unrelated searchBar. Lastly *search on tableview?* - you don't search on a tableView - you search the tableView dataSource which is the data that backs the tableView.